# Magento 2 - Is it safe to delete 'var/vendor' directory?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

I quiet often come across suggestions in forums asking to delete all the directories (below) under `var/` as a fix to other problems

```
var/cache
var/composer_home
var/log
var/page_cache
var/vendor
var/view_preprocessed
```

Is it safe to do this? Especially I am curious about `var/vendor`. Will this directory be recreated after I delete it?

Comment: yes you can delete that one.

Answer (score 1):

See I have seen many developers doing that and they experience no issue. So my answer id yes you can

But I always use this command rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/* var/cache/* generated/* var/page_cache/*

Might this help you